# how to fix an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I have checked alot of posts but still cannot find the answer to an error in one of my tables on my database.
When i run a query in SQL i get the following:

```
Error
SQL query:

0 SQL = INSERT INTO yurzk_user_usergroup_map( user_id, group_id ) 
VALUES ( 140 ) , ( 8 )
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0 SQL=INSERT INTO yurzk_user_usergroup_map (user_id,group_id) VALUES (140),(8)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `user_id` is an autoincrement field and `140` and `8` are two different `group_id`:

```
insert into urzk_user_usergroup_map( `user_id`, `group_id` ) VALUES (NULL, '140'), (NULL, '8')
```

or if `140`is the `user_id` and `8` the `group_id`

```
insert into urzk_user_usergroup_map( `user_id`, `group_id` ) VALUES ('140', '8')
```

Answer (score 0):

the Values part should'nt look like

```
 VALUES ( 140 ) , ( 8 )
```

instead it should look like

```
 VALUES ( 140 , 8 )
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO yurzk_user_usergroup_map (user_id,group_id) VALUES (140,8);`

This is the correct syntax, check out.